# Can I ask this question on Unix&Linux?

Tags: discussion

I am not sure the issue is caused by hardware or the Linux system.

---

My host machine is always stuck recently. and sometimes also black screen.

And when I start my host machine(CentOS 7.2), it records those information in the `/var/log/messages`:

[image]

The logs is below:

```
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:ff:12.0: BAR 5: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:ff:12.4: BAR 1: no space for [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:ff:12.4: BAR 1: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:ff:12.4: BAR 3: no space for [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:ff:12.4: BAR 3: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:ff:12.4: BAR 5: no space for [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:ff:12.4: BAR 5: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci_bus 0000:ff: Some PCI device resources are unassigned, try booting with pci=realloc
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 2: no space for [mem size 0x00000040]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 2: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000040]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 4: no space for [mem size 0x00000040]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000040]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.4: BAR 2: no space for [mem size 0x00000040]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.4: BAR 2: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000040]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.4: BAR 4: no space for [mem size 0x00000040]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.4: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000040]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 1: no space for [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 1: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 3: no space for [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 3: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 5: no space for [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 5: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.4: BAR 1: no space for [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.4: BAR 1: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.4: BAR 3: no space for [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.4: BAR 3: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
```

What's wrong with my host machine?

---

So, can I ask this question on Unix&Linux? or which SE site is suitable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why not. You seem to have a problem with your Linux machine and want to ask how to fix it and what's wrong. That's precisely what the site is for.

It would be better to give some more information though. Explain exactly how the machine gets stuck, when it happens (on boot? randomly? only in GUI?), give us more details on your hardware (especially your graphics card and the driver you use with it), the state of your disk drives (`df -h`) etc.

Apart from that, yes, go for it. Ask your question.

Comment: it is randomly.

Comment: I means if the issue is caused by the hardware, I can ask here ? I am not sure if is caused by the hardware.

Comment: @lustre you don't know if it is the hardware. It might be, or it might not be. So yes, you can ask. If you were 100% sure the problem was bad hardware, then there would be no point in asking anyway since there is nothing you can do. Since you don't know, just ask.